# how to pass default value from database to mapfield panel in wagtail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

This is my code.zoom_level is a column in my model, so i want to pass the respective value as default zoom value in my mapfieldpanel

```
zoom_level = models.CharField(max_length=255)

MapFieldPanel('latlng_address',latlng=True,zoom=zoom_level)
```

but i am getting error like

```
Object of type 'CharField' is not JSON serializable
```

I tried `MapFieldPanel('latlng_address',latlng=True,zoom='zoom_level')`,
zoom_level is passing as a string.How i can pick the value from database and pass it as a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an instance of `CharField` as the default, instead of the actual `zoom_level` value. Also, I think it would be better to pass an Integer for the zoom value.

I'm not too well-versed on wagtailgmaps, but looking at the source, I don't think it is possible to pass an instance variable or callable to MapFieldPanel, so I think what you want to do is not possible.